# md-select won't show currently selected value when bound via formControlName using @angular/material 2.0.0-beta.1 and angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am unable to get a select to show the currently selected value when using reactive forms and form builder.

I've created what essentially boils down to a master/detail component.  I am able to bind and list a set of items on the left and have a form on the right that is bound to a "current record" using a form group.

I have stripped it down to a bare bones example that only contains an md-select and a button to simulate selecting a new record from the list.

Here is the form:

```
<form [formGroup]="frm">
    <md-select placeholder="Food i would like to eat" formControlName="frmControl">
        <md-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value"> {{ food.viewValue }} </md-option>
    </md-select>
    <button md-button (click)="setValue()">SET VALUE</button>
</form>
```

Here is the component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'select-demo',
    templateUrl: 'select-demo.html',
    styleUrls: ['select-demo.css'],
})
export class SelectDemo {

  frm: FormGroup;

  foods = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder){
    this.frm = this._fb.group({
      frmControl: []
    });
  }

  setValue() {
    this.frm.patchValue({ frmControl: 'steak-0 '});
  }
}
```

If I output the form group to the screen using {{ frm.value | json }} I can see that it is in fact being updated as the value becomes 'steak-0' however the select doesn't change.

I would expect that the item in the list with the value 'steak-0' would get be selected and show in the UI as if I clicked the control and selected it manually from the list.

In fact, if I do manually select a value from the list and then click the button, it actually clears the currently selected value and the floating label falls back down as if there is no selected value.

This scenario does (kind of) work for the md-input-container as the selected value shows in the control properly, however the label doesn't float like it is supposed to...but that'll be a different SO question. ;)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This was an oversight on my part, the md-select options were being populated with an object that converted ids to a string and the records were using the numbers as a number...that's what happens when you only get a few hours of sleep the night before.  Hope this helps someone else catch the same mistake before wasting way too much time like I did...

Comment: Would you mind explaining this in a bit more detail. I have similar issue. I am populating select with enum values & the default value set is not being selected

Comment: I dont see any numbers in the question tho

Comment: This should fix the issue https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5079

Comment: Just to clarify a little, the data for the select list items looked something like [{ text: 'One', value: '1' }, { text: 'Two', value: '2' }] and the 'record' looked something like { selectedValue: 1 } and because 1 doesn't equal '1' the record didn't match any value in the list and so nothing was selected.

Answer (score -1):

How about use ng-model?

```
[form]
<md-select ng-model="selectedFood" ng-model-options="{trackBy: 'food.value'}">
    <md-option ng-value="food.value" ng-repeat="food in foods track by food.value">
        {{food.viewValue}}
    </md-option>
</md-select>

[component]
selectedFood = 'pizza-1';

selectedFood will change by your select value
```

Comment: Sorry. The answer does not address the question. There is no reason to accept this as an aswer

Comment: ng-repeat and ng-model are the angularjs syntax . How these are working here?